# How to get YouTube URL from Database and display Video In view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to Get youtube URL which is stored in database and display in the view. While saving into the database I am saving the complete URL like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is0A9x8q_zA".

But with below code nothing display. I cannot store only ID (**is0A9x8q_zA**) from the above URL into the database, because I am storing different type of URL inside the same table like youtube url, blogs URL, tutorial URLs. 
How do I display youtube video? Is there a better option?

My View code :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
     @foreach (var item in group)
     {
     if (item.urltype == "YouTube")
     {
           <iframe src=@Url.Content(item.url) width="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to embed Youtube video, you need to provide different URL. You can use that URL from the database to get the id and apply a different format to a "src" attribute

**Your view file**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
     @foreach (var item in group)
     {
     if (item.urltype == "YouTube")
     {
           //get URI first
           var videoURI = new URI(item.url);
           //get video id from URI
           var videoId = var videoId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(videoUrl.Query).Get("v");
           <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/@videoId" width="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     }
</div>
```

*I hope this helps.*

Answer (score 0):

Check generated HTML (Browser Dev tools : Inspect element) to make sure URL is getting loaded properly.

Also, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

has an example. Hope it helps.